# Cmake : include directory - parent directory

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

```
myproject/
  lib/
  src/
  project2/
    **CMakeLists.txt**
    test.cpp
```

I wrote `CMakeLists.txt` for compile `'test.cpp'` file.
I'd like to `include /src` because i should access src's file.

How could i include src file above?
I tried like `set(MORE_INCLUDE_DIR "-I${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../../` 
but it's not working.

I should compile `'test.cpp'` seperately
please somebody help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `MORE_INCLUDE_DIR`? You should call `include_directories` or `target_include_directories`.

Comment: sorry for abstract comments. MORE_INCLUDE_DIR used for set include_directories.
Could i set include_directories at parent directory based on CMAKE_SOURCE DIRECTORY?

Comment: Instead of `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../../` you probably mean `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../`. BTW, using `message()` command you may print value of any variable, and check its value.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for comment:) I already modified it and it couldn't find path. In this case, Am i wrong at other part?

Comment: It is difficult to say where you are wrong, because you show neither the **code** (`CMakeLists.txt`), which sets include directory, nor **exact error message**. According to *explicit* setting of `-I` option, it seems that you misunderstand CMake concepts. But again, without the code we can only guess.

Comment: @arrowd and Tsyvarev,  thank you for reply. I solved this include_directorise and i understood wrongly about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In this case, cmake required absolute path not relative. Let's try call include_directories like this:

```
    get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR ../ ABSOLUTE)
    include_directories(${PARENT_DIR}/src)
```

It can help.

Comment: In this example, how would your actual code properly include files from the src directory? I have a root folder, then in that root folder I have a "src" and a "test" dir. I'm writing a CMakeLists.txt that's in my "test" folder, but I want to include files from "src". If I add those 2 lines to the CMake file, but from within my test code I want to include a header from "src", how would I do it, if I can't put a ".." in the include path.